# Adsense ads are showing only in one page

Tags: html, google-ads-api, adsense

I am facing a weird situation .

I have some php and html pages in my hosted website , the adsense is showing blank ads in all these page except one which is `http://MyUrl.website/test.php` even if the files contains the same data.

Example : two files : test.php and empty.php containing the same code :

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
 <ins class="adsbygoogle" 
style="display:block" 
data-ad-format="fluid" 
data-ad-layout-key="-8h+1t-dj+em+ev" 
data-ad-client="ca-pub-6000587445822697" 
data-ad-slot="6666706706"></ins> 
<script> (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
 </script>
    <h1>ads above</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now after opening these files :

`http://MyUrl.website/test.php`  : Shows ad

`https://MyUrl.website/test.php` : Shows blank ad

`http://MyUrl.website/empty.php` : Shows blank ad

PS : I've tried to change the ads , and even put another ads from another adsense and it doesn't work

PS 2 : Im not sure if there is any relation but my adword account has been suspended

Comment: *"Im not sure if there is any relation but my adword account has been suspended"* - There ya' go ;)

Comment: @Adam a friend gave me his ads to put in my website and Im still facing this problem ,

Comment: his adword is activated